# DNS lookup fail with VirtualHost on EC2

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, apache-2.4

Setup: 2 websites as VirtualHosts on an EC2 running Amazon Linux. One of which the domain name resolves with no trouble (charlesrobertsonarts.com), the other returns server not found from all browsers (nigelyons.com). Both of them have domain names registered with Bluehost which direct to Route 53 DNS. There they have type A hosted zone entries pointing to an Elastic IP (52.203.82.91) for the EC2. Apache has name based VirtualHost entries in its httpd.conf file.

Other VirtualHosts at that IP work just fine with this setup, and I can access the site by adding an entry to my hosts file (52.203.82.91 nigelyons.com). I've searched high and low and am truly baffled as to what is the problem here. Any help would be appreciated.

route 53 hosted zones:
[image: route 53 hosted zones]

`httpd.conf`:
[image: httpd.conf]

Answer (score 2):

You said that you can't reach nigelyons.com in your browser, but that's not true. You *can* reach it just fine. It sends a redirect to www.nigelyons.com.

It's *that* site that you can't reach.

And the reason you can't reach it is that it doesn't have an A record in the DNS.

To resolve the problem, create a record set in Route 53 for www, containing the appropriate A record. Then wait; negative caching means it could be an hour or more before it becomes accessible.

Comment: Beat me by 8 seconds, you fiend!